# What is the best Set-Up for insane mode in Castle Crashers?

Tags: castle-crashers

I'm pretty new to this game and I got to insane mode(my friend helped me) but when I play on insane mode it seems that I'm under powered.(and I don't know how to juggle that well) So I was wondering if there is a good set-up(in stats) that would make the game easier for me in insane mode. And if you know can write down how to juggle for the ps3 please.

Comment: Updated my answer because surprisingly heavyweight enemies can be juggled!

Answer (score 2):

For insane mode the stats **Defense** and **Agility** are the most important to have points invested in. This is because the enemies are strong and agile, you definitely want to counter this.

The **Strength** and **Magic** stats are for damaging your opponent and are less important because a hit means experience points, so low attack stats should get you more exp.

There are a couple ways to juggle but the most basic combo is this:

- □ □ △ (in air against AI) Square + Square + Triangle
- □ □ △ △ (in air against AI) Square + Square + Triangle + Triangle

To juggle middleweight enemies you can do this (this combo also let's you hover in the air indefinitely):

- □ △ △ (in air) Square + Triangle + Triangle

Remember, not all enemies can be easily juggled. Only the lightweight are relatively easy to juggle. Middleweight enemies can be juggled using the combo above but heavyweights + most of the beefy enemies require advanced juggles.

There is also an "easy" way to defeat some levels on insane mode:

- Arrow spamming with 2 or more players (need full agility stat)
- Skipping levels (need other player who already beat it and can only be done on certain levels, mostly non-boss levels)

More tips:

- There is always **ONE** enemy that actively follows you around, try to focus on this enemy.
- The D-Pad let's you have more control over the X & Y-axis movement which is crucial to juggling. This is just a preference though.